# What is the best way do draw an strike text with iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, drawing, quartz-2d

What is the best way do draw an strike text with iPhone sdk?

I want to draw a strike text like the  tag do on html.

Is there any method to do this? or I should draw an line my self over the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by subclassing UILabel and override draw rect.

I have created an [git](https://github.com/terentealex/StrikeUILabel) for this.